# How are transactions on large data done in a smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, contract-invocation

I am presently working on a project involving read and write operations on a huge database. The database is structured in such a way that there is a key, and for the key there is a corresponding set of data. Now, I would like to consider each of these operations as `transactions` in a smart contract. There are two ways of doing this:

1. Construct a `struct` that would contain the `key` as well as the `set of data` corresponding to the `key`.
2. Simply store the `keys` and a `pointer` to the `set of data` stored in an external database. I was thinking of using [Oraclize](http://docs.oraclize.it/#overview) for accessing the database.

If the first option is considered, it is definitely not a practical choice as storing such large data directly on a blockchain is not possible. But if the second option is considered, then isn't the external database prone to tampering, thus having no point to build it on a blockchain.

Effectively, I am looking for building a blockchain based application that deals with Big data keeping the security of the data in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed - if the data is not stored and structured properly - it is prone to tampering.

One of the solutions is to store a cryptographic hash in the blockchain and structure your data in such a way that it is possible to reliably calculate the hash to verify it has not been tampered.

You can do it in many different ways - in the end it is going to be something resembling a Merkele tree. IPFS is the most straightforward option - the data is kept in such a way that it is identified by its cryptographic hash that you store in the Ethereum contract.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion....but what if the data is still too large considering I store only the `key` and the `hash` of the corresponding data?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. You can calculate a single hash of a very large dataset.